# Give Default Checked Value To The Checkbox Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I tried to add checked property to a specific checkbox using jquery, but it seems doesn't work properly.

Checkbox Function Display

```
function product_category_loop_array ($product_category_array = array (), $parent_id = 0, $margin = -20) {
            if (!empty ($product_category_array[$parent_id])) {
                $margin = $margin + 20;
                foreach ($product_category_array[$parent_id] as $items) {
                    echo "<input style='margin: 0 0 0 ".$margin."px; overflow: hidden;' id='".$items['id']."' class='category_checkbox left' name='product_category[]' type='checkbox' value='".$items['id']."'><label class='category_checkbox_label left'>".$items['name']."</label>
                    <div class='clear'></div>";
                    product_category_loop_array ($product_category_array, $items["id"], $margin);
                }
            }
        }
        function product_category () {
            $db_connect = mysqli_connect (db_host, db_username, db_password, db_name);
            $product_category_query = $db_connect->query ("SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM `product_category` ORDER BY name ASC");
            $product_category_array = array ();
            if (mysqli_num_rows ($product_category_query)) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($product_category_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    $product_category_array[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
                }
                product_category_loop_array ($product_category_array);
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs-2" class="product_detail hide">
                            <div class="left">
                                <form class="product_detail_form" method="post" action="">
                                    <?php product_category () ?>
                                    <p class="detail_submit"><input name="save_product_category" type="submit" value="Save"></p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
    $ (document) .ready (function () {
        <?php echo $hide_div ?>;
        var selected_array = <?php echo json_encode ($product_category_selected) ?>;
        $.each (selected_array (key, value) {
            $ ("#"+value).prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you ve a json inside selected_array.... $.each wants an array

Comment: Your php seems incorrect. same function call in the foreach loop, what is the outcome of this can you post that html in the question you posted?

Comment: Why don't you add `checked` property to the html itself instead of using js?

Comment: Edited. That is my whole script to display the category tree. And I need to give checked attribute to the selected category based on database.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ ("#"+value).attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        <?php echo $hide_div ?>;
        // DECODE JSON IN JS
        var selected_array = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode ($product_category_selected) ?>);
        $.each(selected_array(key, value) {
            $("#" + value).prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```